# secondary permission request is never presented

Tags: android, android-permissions

This is a rewrite of my original post because I have found that, contrary to Permissions overview:

- a) The secondary permission dialog is never displayed
- b) After
  clicking "Deny" for the initial permission dialog, it is never shown
  again.

Therefore, if I click deny, I can never allow calendar permission.

I set permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
```

On start, I check for calendar permissions in MainActivity because they are necessary for the user to add appointments via my app and make them available to Google calendar (this works, if I allow, my app adds the calendar):

```
    AccessCalendar accessCalendar = new AccessCalendar();
    if(accessCalendar.requestCalendarPermissions(mContext, this)){
        /**
         * calendar read and write permissions not allowed: explain why needed
         */
        Log.d(TAG, "calendar read and write permissions not allowed: explain why needed");
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
        Snackbar.make(constraintLayout, R.string.write_calendar_permission_explanation, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        DialogFragment permissionDialog = new CalendarPermissionExplanationFragment();
        try {
            permissionDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "CalendarPermissionExplanationFragment");
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "exception e is: " + e);
        }

    }else{
        /**
         * calendar read and write permissions allowed! No need to explain
         */
        Log.d(TAG, "calendar read and write permissions allowed! No need to explain");
    }
```

AccessCalendar.requestCalendarPermissions is (pretty much plagarized from Request App Permissions):

```
public boolean requestCalendarPermissions(Context context, Activity activity){
    Log.d(TAG, "Entered: requestCalendarPermissions");
    boolean explain = false;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
        // Permission is not granted
        Log.d(TAG, "read and write permission not granted");
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) &&
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale is true");
            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.write_calendar_permission_explanation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            explain = true;
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale is false");
            // No explanation needed; request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALENDAR);
            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }else{
        //permission is granted, so set permission to true
        Log.d(TAG, "read and write calendar permissions granted");
    }
    return explain;
}
```

Due to some problems, I am forced to use Toast to provide an explanation. I am now presented with the initial permissions dialog who's request attempt, Deny or Allow, is handled by MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult():

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    Log.d(TAG, "Entered: onRequestPermissionsResult");
    Log.d(TAG, "requestCode is: " + requestCode);
    Log.d(TAG, "permissions is: " + permissions);
    Log.d(TAG, "grantResults is: " + grantResults);
    int cntPermissions = grantResults.length;
    if(cntPermissions > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cntPermissions; i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "permissions[" + i + "] is: " + permissions[i]);
        }
    }
    int cntGrantResults = grantResults.length;
    if(cntGrantResults > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cntGrantResults; i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "grantResults[" + i + "] is: " + grantResults[i]);
        }
    }
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALENDAR:
            Log.d(TAG, "Entered: case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALENDAR");
            if(cntPermissions > 0) {
                if(permissions[1].equals("android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR") && grantResults[1] == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.write_calendar_permission, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    AccessCalendar accessCalendar = new AccessCalendar();
                    accessCalendar.createCalendar(mContext, this);
                    //get calendar information again to see if petrecords calendar was created
                    Log.d(TAG, "get the calendars in the system to see if petrecords now exists");
                    accessCalendar.getCalendars(mContext, this);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_no_write_calendar_permission, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "create alertdialog to explain why the permission is required");
                }
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "no permissions returned");
            }
            break;
        default:
            Log.d(TAG, "illegal requestCode value");
            break;
    }
    return;
}
```

In that case, a new calendar is created. Otherwise, the user proceeds after Denying. Later, the user is presented with Appointments and may, at that point, desire to add an appointment via my app and so clicks the Appointment tab and then the Manage Appointments button. At that point, precisely the same code is entered to check calendar permissions as shown above.

At that point I expect to be presented with the secondary permissions dialog, but no, all I get is my explanation. I would also expect to see the secondary permissions dialog when I relaunch my app after initially Denying, but no.

So, why doesn't Android ever present the secondary permissions dialog?

Comment: Do you have both `READ_CALENDAR` and `WRITE_CALENDAR` `<uses-permission>` elements in the manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` method implies that the permission was rejected before and that you should explain why you're asking for the permissions.

For this you should use a `Dialog` or `Snackbar` with an action the user can use to trigger the permission request again.

If you're app doesn't work without this permission, you might want to show a bigger screen explaining that the app doesn't work without.

You could even ignore the `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` flag and just show the permission request again and again. That's very annoying though.

Comment: The Android information makes it sound as though the system itself will generate another request dialog, now with a "Never ask again" check box, but it does not. How would I do that?

Comment: Just by calling `requestPermissions()` again.

Comment: OK. Currently, that's commented out (see the code at FOR TEST)  because when I do that, I enter a loop that doesn't exit until I select Allow, which the user may not want to do and they also may not want to select "Don't ask again" either. And, "Don't ask again" crashes the app.

Comment: Yes. That's the side effect of my last paragraph. If you want to do it properly, show a alert dialog instead of the Toast. When the user clicks the positive button, request the permissions again.

Comment: OK. I added a simple OK to a DialogFragment, launched immediately in MainActivity at app launch, that explains why permission is required and at clicking OK, a permission request is made again and thus the secondary permission dialog is displayed. Thanks!